# Windows Store Apps/ Metro Apps : ListView data binding error

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm working on Windows Store App/ Metro UI app where it takes data from AppSettings and bind those data in ListView. 
This is the code for **data.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var dataSource = new Array();
    var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List();

    var appData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
    var roamingSettings = appData.localSettings;
    var json = roamingSettings.values["reminderList"];
    if (json != undefined) {
        dataSource = JSON.parse(json);


        for (var i in dataSource) {
            var rem = dataSource[i];
            dataList.push(rem);
        }

    }
    // Create a namespace to make the data publicly
    // accessible. 
    var publicMembers =
        {
            itemList: dataList
        };
    WinJS.Namespace.define("MyData", publicMembers);
})();
```

And this is the code for ListView I used.

```
<div id="basicListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
            data-win-options="{ itemDataSource : MyData.itemList.dataSource, itemTemplate:select('#mediumListIconTextTemplate') }">
```

But when there's one item in storage, it shows as **undefined** in ListView.
And when there're more than one item in AppSettings, it gives me below error.

```
{
    "exception": null,
    "error": [
        [{
            "description": "Out of stack space",
            "number": -2146828260,
            "stack": "Error: Out of stack space\n   at getProperty (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8283:13)\n   at get (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8566:36)\n   at getProperty (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8283:13)\n   at get (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8566:36)\n   at getProperty (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8283:13)\n   at get (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8566:36)\n   at getProperty (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8283:13)\n   at get (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8566:36)\n   at getProperty (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8283:13)\n   at get (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8566:36)"
        }]
    ],
    "promise": {
        "_oncancel": null,
        "_nextState": null,
        "_state": {
            "name": "error",
            "done": null,
            "then": null
        },
        "_listeners": null,
        "_value": [
            [{
                "description": "Out of stack space",
                "number": -2146828260,
                "stack": "Error: Out of stack space\n   at getProperty (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8283:13)\n   at get (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8566:36)\n   at getProperty (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8283:13)\n   at get (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8566:36)\n   at getProperty (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8283:13)\n   at get (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8566:36)\n   at getProperty (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8283:13)\n   at get (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8566:36)\n   at getProperty (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8283:13)\n   at get (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js:8566:36)"
            }]
        ],
        "_isException": false,
        "_errorId": 7
    },
    "id": 7
}
```

Can anyone please point me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

How does your template `mediumListIconTextTemplate` look like? Does it match with your JSON object which you use to construct the data list? I doubt it is.

Also when you say the error is raised, could you also provide the stack trace?

It would be helpful to analyze the problem, if you post your sample JSON as well as definition of `mediumListIconTextTemplate`.